# Python : simialar pattern not matching

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am using regex to match these two url:

```
url1 = 'https://lh3.ggpht.com/7KNQ1LHpGSfsJUvNJSihLmbFDJn6u2vMjUW96UEDe8400giVKnUYrtqnJqlDepYTJw=h310'

url2 = 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/L8mE0Qo69BNhkWqBKMlRKLV189SwS5OneIQjqmAekjbCV2RT7tEo_djy-W4OBX0QJ-0=h310'
```

and the pattern I used is :

```
pat = 'https://\w+\.ggpht.com/+\w+=+\w+'
```

the error is that url1 matches to the pattern but url2 does not and as far as I can see both the url follow the same pattern. Anybody knows a fix or a common pattern??

Comment: Are you trying to match only these two urls?

Comment: These two urls are exactly the same.

Comment: The two URLs are exactly *equal*. Did you paste the wrong string into your question, perhaps?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad I copied the same url by mistake. There done editing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have a list of similar url. And the same problem arises some match while some don't. I figured by taking just 2 url at a time I will be able to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second pattern contains dashes in the string you are trying to match, while `\w` only includes letters, digits and the `_` underscore.

Add the `-` into a character class:

```
r'https://\w+\.ggpht.com/[\w-]+=\w+'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> url1 = 'https://lh3.ggpht.com/7KNQ1LHpGSfsJUvNJSihLmbFDJn6u2vMjUW96UEDe8400giVKnUYrtqnJqlDepYTJw=h310'
>>> url2 = 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/L8mE0Qo69BNhkWqBKMlRKLV189SwS5OneIQjqmAekjbCV2RT7tEo_djy-W4OBX0QJ-0=h310'
>>> pat = r'https://\w+\.ggpht.com/[\w-]+=+\w+'
>>> re.search(pat, url1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 93), match='https://lh3.ggpht.com/7KNQ1LHpGSfsJUvNJSihLmbFDJn>
>>> re.search(pat, url2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 94), match='https://lh4.ggpht.com/L8mE0Qo69BNhkWqBKMlRKLV189S>
```

Comment: Thanks it works...can you please explain me what's happening with [\w-] I am new to regex. And can we even use this pat = 'https://\w+\.ggpht.com/(\w-)?\w+=+\w+' will this pattern also work?

Comment: @user3772366: `\w` is a *built-in* character class, `[..]` is a custom character class. You can incorporate a built-in class into a custom class, so `[\w]` is essentially the same as `\w`. To that I added `-`, so that `[\w-]` matches everything `\w` matches *plus* a dash.

Comment: `(\w-)?` is something entirely different. It means: match a `\w` character, then a dash, but this pattern is optional. The pattern doesn't match either of your urls.

Comment: oh I got thanks for such a good explanation :)